# Serenity Headless Chrome crashes occasionally while Non-headless Chrome never crash

Tags: java, google-chrome, headless, serenity-bdd

I'm using Serenity framwork to run our test cases. When I enable Chrome headless mode and execute，some cases will fail occasionally (40/900 cases) because of Chrome crash/can't be opened. But if I disable headless mode, this issue will never occur. Here is the log:

```
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: Could not instantiate class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    Caused by: net.thucydides.core.webdriver.DriverConfigurationError: 
    Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (unknown error: unable to discover open pages
    Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
    System info: host: '****', ip: '****', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
    Driver info: driver.version: ProvideNewDriver
    remote stacktrace: Backtrace:
        Ordinal0 [0x009F87E3+2852835]
        Ordinal0 [0x008E5BB1+1727409]
        Ordinal0 [0x007BE4B9+517305]
        Ordinal0 [0x00750B3B+68411]
        Ordinal0 [0x0074D3A0+54176]
        Ordinal0 [0x0076D9F7+186871]
        Ordinal0 [0x0076D7FD+186365]
        Ordinal0 [0x0076B70B+177931]
        Ordinal0 [0x00752584+75140]
        Ordinal0 [0x00753650+79440]
        Ordinal0 [0x007535E9+79337]
        Ordinal0 [0x008FAD5C+1813852]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B1C616+1075574]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B1C367+1074887]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B27497+1120247]
        GetHandleVerifier [0x00B1CC16+1077110]
        Ordinal0 [0x008F3206+1782278]
        Ordinal0 [0x008FC3BB+1819579]
        Ordinal0 [0x008FC523+1819939]
        Ordinal0 [0x00912B45+1911621]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x7670F989+25]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x770674A4+228]
        RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77067474+180]
```

Serenity.properties:

```
webdriver.driver=chrome
webdriver.timeout.implicitlywait = 10
webdriver.timeout.fluentwait = 10
serenity.take.screenshots=FOR_FAILURES
serenity.console.colors = true
chrome_preferences.download.default_directory = C:\\serenityDataDownload
chrome_preferences.profile.default_content_settings.popups=0
chrome_preferences.download.prompt_for_download=false
webdriver.chrome.driver = libs/chromedriver/win32/chromedriver.exe
```

More information:

```
Chrome version: 84.0.4147.105
ChromeDriver version: 84.0.4147.30
Serenity version 2.1.8
Serenity cucumber version 1.9.45
```

Has anyone encountered such a similar problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a Chromedriver bug, as indicated by the stack trace.

Comment: Yeah, it seems occur since Chrome83. Our current solution is using -Dfailsafe.rerunFailingTestsCount=2 to rerun those failed cases. We are considering to kill all chrome/chromedriver tasks before each Scenario to resolve this problem. Any suggestions？